# How do you craft powdered grim cap?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

This ingredient is mentioned in a scroll:

[image: Getting very close to the formula! Mixing a powdered grim cap with a witch flower almost works. I think I'm missing one more ingredient.]

While I don't have a witch flower yet, I would be interested in how to make powdered grim cap. Maybe it is used in other recipes which I have not yet discovered. Adding different amounts of grim cap with/without flasks to the mortar did not give any results.

Comment: I presume you just need a bottle, grim cap and witch flower and you've got a potion.. but I haven't gotten that far yet... :)

Comment: Yeah, presumably making it into a powder is part of the alchemical process, not something the player does by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mixed a grim cap, blooddrop blossom (the descritions says: Witches of the north use them in dark rituals.) and a cave nettle. What I get is a Sulphurous Potion (Rage: Attack Power +10, Evasion -10).
Maybe this is meant?

Comment: I agree. I don't think you have to "powder" the grim cap before using it.

Comment: Yeah That is what the mortar and pestle does for you.